# How to get the file id using Box API

Tags: configuration, get, box-api

I have created created How to a new web app integration with the help of this documentation of [Box api documentation](https://developers.box.com/box-web-application-integrations/). 
When i right click on a pdf file i can see my application.
Now i need to know how to configure my application to get the file id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the "Callback Parameters" section of your Web App Integration.[image]

Within the Callback Parameters section you can choose whether what your application is expecting is a `GET` or `POST` request or a file object (in cases where you would like the file itself to be sent to your application) and input a parameter name that you would like to receive for the value. Then you can click into the box for Parameter Value to see a dropdown of the available parameters that can be sent to your application with a short description of what each one returns. The one you're looking for in this case is the **file_id**, which will show up as `#file_id#` once you click it, as in the screenshot provided.